# Implement aggregations for analytics using key store and mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, redis, analytics, aggregation

Iam trying to build basic analytics service that will show daily aggregations of few keys (counter site-hits per day, counter purchases per day). I am probably going to have more.

My idea was to use redis that will collect the daily counters and once in few hours to flush this data into mysql with date. this way ill be able to enjoy Redis in-memory capabilities and later on using mysql for the analytic queries.

Do you think that could work out? any thoughts using it differently ?

Thank you.

Comment: You can use redis in this case. And use some prefix like YYYYMMDDHH to store the keys. Then after every hour you can run a cron job to get all keys from redis from the past hour (using prefix match ) and push the data into sql database. Let me know if you know further explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly this will work. So will simply writing your records to MySQL, without the intermediate step of Redis.  You should consider simplifying your project until you have so much traffic that your simple implementation can't keep up.

You should consider using the MariaDB 10.2 fork of MySQL. That fork has windowing and ranking functions, which may come in very handy for analytical work.

Comment: So you suggest to write everything straight to mysql.. but Iam doing aggregations that means for every raw data ill need to do 3 operations: select (to retrieve the current data) , increase , update the record back. Dont you think it will be dead-end within very short time? thanks.

Comment: `UPDATE table SET col = col+? WHERE id = ?`  will increment a record in MySQL or any SQL system in one operation. Redis has a similar setup, of course.

Comment: what about daily aggregations? how you going to arrange those?